# PyDev won't start in Aptana Studio3

Tags: python, aptana, pydev

Aptana Studio is my primary Python IDE and I have been using it for years with much joy and success! Recently, when I start Aptana Studio it fails to recognize any PyDev projects that I have previously created. I noticed that this was happening after installing a recent update of the IDE. I tried uninstalling Aptana and resinstalling the latest version from the website. Nada...I updated Java thinking there might be a misalignment between Java versions or something like that. Nada...The latest version of Eclipse works fine and Aptana seems to be functioning correctly for everything except for PyDev (Python).

I am running a current version of Windows 8. Does anyone know how to fix this or maybe trouble shoot the problem? PyDev worked perfectly in Aptana Studio until I installed the update. Has anyone come across this and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I went back to the Aptana website and this time around it gave me Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805 which works fine. 3.5.0 does still not appear to work for Python development at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get PyDev 3.0 installed along Aptana Studio 3 Release Candidate update site:

http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/rc/

Other update sites available are documented [there](http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/) (click on the Aptana Studio tab).

This [recent bug](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8079) should be watched for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana 3.5.0 and PyDev 3.0 does not work under Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks yet. PyDev reports builtin symbols such as None could not be recognized.

I rolled back to 3.4.2 as well.